# Return all values when filter text box is empty

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access form And I want to return all values when I leave a filter text box (e.g Me.Text23 ) blank or empty

This is my code:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "Report", acViewPreview, " select * from main where border LIKE'" & _ 
me.Text23 & "' AND a_date Between #" & Format(Me.Text18, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & _ 
"# And #" & Format(Me.Text20, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#"
```

Comment: Avoid using capital letters in every word. It is very annoying to read (and grammatically incorrect).

Comment: I think you are using `LIKE` incorrectly. Do you want to filter using the exact value? Then use `=` instead of `LIKE`. If you want to match a pattern the use `LIKE` with wildcards (`*` or `?`).

Comment: @Mett maybe he enters the wildcards straight into the Text23 field.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
... "select * from main where " & iif(me.Text23 <> "", " border like " & me.Text.23 & " and ", "") & "a_date between #" ....
```

Read about `iif` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: You should be more specific, if you really want to get help.

Comment: it said compile error:
expected:end of statement
and itis mark on(between)

Comment: Do you realize that I just showed you a small piece of code to illustrate the approach and that you have to incorporate it in your code? Show us your resulting code.

Comment: DoCmd.OpenReport "Report", acViewPreview, " select * from main where & iif(me.Text23 <> "", " border like "  & me.Text23 & "  AND a_date Between #" & Format(Me.Text18, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & _
    "# And #" & Format(Me.Text20, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#"

Comment: You forgot the third argument to iif. Look closer at my example, the third argument should be an empty line ("")

Comment: is this right



DoCmd.OpenReport "Report", acViewPreview, " select * from main where & iif(me.Text23 <> "", " border like " & me.Text23 & " and ", "")  AND a_date Between #" & Format(Me.Text18, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & _
    "# And #" & Format(Me.Text20, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#"



itis give me error with(border)

Comment: it give me an error before this statement  "") its give an error with word (border)

Comment: Torvin, in MS Access, an empty textbox is null, except for very odd circumstances, not an empty string. "" is not the same as null.

Comment: Remou what i do (if i leave this textbox empty i want to retrive all value )

please check my code

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "Report", acViewPreview, , "border LIKE '" & _
Replace(Me.Text23 & "", "'", "''") & "*' AND a_date Between #" & _
Format(Me.Text18, "yyyy/mm/dd") & _
"# And #" & Format(Me.Text20, "yyyy/mm/dd") & "#"
```

I recommend that you put proper names on textboxes, such as txtStartDate.
Using a year, month, day format avoids locale problems.
The WHERE argument of OpenReport accepts a string similar to an SQL WHERE argument, but without any extra bits.
Replacing single quotes with two single quotes avoids problems with strings containing quotes.

If Text23 is empty, the WHERE statement reads `LIKE '*'`, which is everything that is not null. If you need null Borders, you need to say so.

Comment: i writed like that _____DoCmd.OpenReport "Report", acViewPreview, " select *  from main where border LIKE '" & Replace(Me.Text23, "'", "''") & "*'  & a_date Between #" & Format(Me.Text18, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & _
    "# And #" & Format(Me.Text20, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#"______when i run it its said runtime error94 invvalid use of NULL______and i used the same code of you and its give me the same error

Comment: pashew, please compare my example and your code. You have a whole bunch of stuff that is not going to work, such as `select *`, and you are missing a comma.

Comment: Dear remou i copied your code and its give me the same error when i am running the program

Comment: Is your report bound to a table or query? Please include the full text for the error.

Comment: it is bound to table
run-time error '94' invalid use of NULL

Comment: Ahh, that is the Replace statement, I have made a correction (see answer)